# Paypal Change Address Field Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, paypal

I'm using WordPress Express Checkout plugin for my Wordpress Website in while paying from Credit or Debit Card button small form shows address filed with the country flag, can I change this flag to a country dropdown list using Css or Jquery?

Paypal Address Field Image:
[image: Paypal Address Field Image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Those credit card fields in your image render in a double-nested PayPal iframe that you have no control over.

The default billing country of the buyer will be set based on their locale ( top of chrome://settings/languages or equivalent , or if set on the SDK line )

Comment: It does not automatically detect my IP, I'm in CA and show US.

Comment: Yeah this actually comes from language-locale

Comment: I ended up having to include &locale=en_CA in my sdk call

Answer (score 0):

For me, including 'locale=en_CA' in my SDK call solved the issue:

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?**locale=en_CA**&client-id
```

My location was not auto detected by my IP.

Comment: The question here is about changing flags to country names, not about overriding the browser locale with a default locale.

Comment: The above line is what allowed me to achieve what the user is asking for in the picture posted.

Comment: They were not asking for what you think they were asking for, so no.